# How to determine lowest/highest index of enum in java?

Tags: java, enums

Suppose there is the enum declaration somewhere in code:

```
enum Colors { RED(100), BLUE(200); }
```

Can I get the lowest/highest index value for that particular enum type presuming I am not aware of the declaration?  Is it possible in java?

Example:

```
int lowIndex = Colors.minIndex(); // should return 100
```

---

Thanks everyone.  So there are no implicit methods to query for min/max defined integer value.  I'll have to iterate through the enum values and determine it from there as you have described.

Comment: What do you mean by "index"?

Comment: So you are trying to get the parameter passed in the enum entry or the index of the entry itself? In the latter case, you can count the length of values and subtract 1 for max, and min will always be 0.

Comment: the 100 and 200 in the declaration.  is there a method to query for min/max integer declared values in an enum?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about array indices at first... Those aren't indices. Those are values that are fed to a constructor; the code you posted by itself isn't compilable. Whether you can access them depends on how the `enum` is structured internally.

Comment: @user3580294 I see.  Those are passed to the constructor then.  So, are there implicit methods of getting the lowest/highest defined integer values?

Comment: No, just like how there are no implicit methods of getting a member for any other regular class.

Comment: @user3580294 But how come there is implicit method to get all enum values like the `<Enum>.values()`?  I was expecting a similar implicit method to get min/max declared int value.

Comment: Because not all enums have a "min/max declared `int` value". Those are things you as the programmer have to put in there specifically for them to exist in the first place. Because that is custom behavior, the compiler cannot make assumptions about how those values are to be retrieved, so it cannot insert methods for you.

Comment: I come from C/C++ background.  Enums are normally just integers.  I presumed int values are not custom behavior, that's why I'm asking the question here.  If java compiler inserted methods to get declared enum values, I don't see how far off my presumption is.  It's even better than C/C++, because C/C++ does not even provide any implicit methods for enums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to iterate over the enum set:

```
for (Color p : Color.values()) {
    // keep track of min "index"
}
```

Remember that an enum is essentially collection of predefined object instances.  RED(100) is calling the Color(int value) constructor.  That said, I could make a color enum with values defined like this:

```
RED("best", 14, 3.33546)
```

Hence, the logic for finding the minimum "index" will be different case by case.

Comment: I chose your post as the answer.  It clarifies the problem I am dealing with.  It's also the first post that clarifies it even though you have similar response to @SimonC

Comment: Fair enough, @bstar55 beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

With index do you mean the ordinal or the integer values given in the enum ?

Anyways this is a simple example that may help you:-

```
enum Mobile {
   Samsung(400), Nokia(250),Motorola(325);

   int price;
   Mobile(int p) { //values in brackets are set to price property in enum
      price = p;
   }
   int showPrice() {
      return price;  //you have to declare methods in enum to return value, there is no predefined function like returnValue()
   } 
}

public class EnumDemo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

     System.out.println("CellPhone List:");
     for(Mobile m : Mobile.values()) {
        System.out.println(m + " costs " + m.showPrice() + " dollars");
     }

     Mobile ret = Mobile.Samsung;
     System.out.println("The ordinal is = " + ret.ordinal());
     System.out.println("MobileName = " + ret.name());                      
   }
}
```

Note that the java.lang.Enum.ordinal() method returns the ordinal of the enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero).

And the output is:-

```
CellPhone List:
Samsung costs 400 dollars
Nokia costs 250 dollars
Motorola costs 325 dollars
The ordinal is = 0
MobileName = Samsung
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't override an enum's 'index'.  What's happening here is that the `Colors` enum has a constructor that takes an `int` as a parameter.  It's up to the implementation of the constructor to store that value.

You could maintain a static map of these values, updated by the enum constructor, that could be queried for min/max values.

Alternatively you could just look over all the enums every time looking for the min/max:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (Colors c in Colors.values())
  max = Math.max(c.getIndex(), max);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this? It "caches" the value when the enum is loaded.

```
public enum Color {

    RED(100),
    BLUE(200);

    public final int val;

    private Color(int val) {
        this.val = val;

        if (Dummy.maxColor == null || Dummy.maxColor.val < val) {
            Dummy.maxColor = this;
        }
    }

    // This seems to be needed because you can't access static fields in enum constructors
    private static class Dummy {
        private static Color maxColor = null;
    }

    public static Color getMaxColor() {
        return Dummy.maxColor;
    }

}
```

Comment: I just want to know the lowest/highest defined integer value for an enum without having to instantiate one.

Comment: @kerafill Enums are instantiated as soon as the class is loaded.